# InPerson Signing is not autofilling signers e-mail

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm running into an issue when I'm creating an in Person Signing session from a composite template.

I follow the same procedure to identify the in person signer as in other API calls that embed the document directly, but in this case, when the in Person Signer finishes the signing process and is asked for an email to send the completed documents to, it's not autofilled with my API provided signerEmail object.

JSON as follows:

```
{
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "templateId": "a6c1a9b2-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3f8efef01946"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "inPersonSigners": [{
                            "name": "Lilly Test",
                            "email": "liltest@company.com",
                            "hostEmail": "liltest@company.com",
                            "hostName": "Lilly Test",
                            "signerName": "Yakue Holguín",
                            "signerEmail": "yholguin@autofill.com",
                            "roleName": "Signer 1",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "clientUserId": "1000",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "emailNotification": {
                                "emailSubject": "Contract for live in person signature attached. Host: Lilly Test",
                                "emailBody": "Contract for live in person signature attached. Host: Lilly Test",
                                "supportedLanguage": "fr"
                            },
                            "requireIdLookUp": "true",
                            "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                            "smsAuthentication": {
                                "senderProvidedNumbers": ["+376342078", "+33672793567", "+34696463366"]
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "signers": [{
                            "name": "John Test",
                            "email": "jtest@company.com",
                            "emailNotification": {
                                "emailSubject": "Contract for live in person signature attached. Host: Lilly Test",
                                "emailBody": "Contract for live in person signature attached. Host: Lilly Test",
                                "supportedLanguage": "en"
                            },
                            "roleName": "Signer 2",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId": "2"
                        }, {
                            "name": "Mary Test",
                            "email": "mtest@company.com",
                            "emailNotification": {
                                "emailSubject": "Contract for live in person signature attached. Host: Lilly Test",
                                "emailBody": "Contract for live in person signature attached. Host: Lilly Test",
                                "supportedLanguage": "en"
                            },
                            "roleName": "Signer 3",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "recipientId": "3"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "customFields": {
                    "textCustomFields": [{
                            "value": "8009E000000JQl2QAG",
                            "required": "false",
                            "show": "false",
                            "name": "##SFContract"
                        }
                    ]
                },
            }
        ]
    }
],
"eventNotification": {
    "RecipientEvents": [{
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "delivered"
        }, {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "declined"
        }
    ],
    "EnvelopeEvents": [{
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Delivered"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "completed"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "sent"
        }, {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Declined"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Is the funcionality different when using a composite template or am I missing something regarding the final "Send completed document to" or "Print" autofill?

Thanks!

Comment: To add to the unexpected behaviour, not all notification e-mails are being sent.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have few parameters you need to remove in the call :
                            "name": "Lilly Test",
                            "email": "liltest@company.com",
Those parameters are only used for classic signers not inPerson signers.
 "clientUserId": "1000",
You should use this one only if it's an embedded signing, and if you use it, we won't send any emails!

Comment: Hi Yvon, removal of the parameters doesn't affect the envelope, but I'll go on with the removal.

Comment: As for the clientUserId, we have config unchecked "Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers", and it's sending the e-mail on the rest of the API calls that don't involve composite templates.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code for InPerson Signers, let us know if it resolves your issue:

```
{
"emailSubject": "Doc Subject",
"emailBlurb": "Doc Blurb",
"status": "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "inPersonSigners": [{
                    "routingOrder": 1,
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "hostEmail": "validDocuSignAccount@email.com",
                    "clientUserId": "OnlyNeededIfEmbeddedSigning",
                    "hostName": "Agent1",
                    "signerName": "Customer1",
                    "tabs": {
                            "signHereTabs": [{
                                "documentId": "1",
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "xPosition": "300",
                                "yPosition": "300"
                            }]
                        }
                },
                {
                    "routingOrder": 1,
                    "recipientId": "2",
                    "hostEmail": "validDocuSignAccount@email.com",
                    "hostName": "Agent2",
                    "signerName": "Customer2",
                    "tabs": {
                            "signHereTabs": [{
                                "documentId": "1",
                                "pageNumber": "1",
                                "recipientId": "1",
                                "xPosition": "500",
                                "yPosition": "500"
                            }]
                        }
                }]
            }
            }
        ],
        "document": {
          "name": "doc_1.pdf",
          "documentId": "1",
          "transformPdfFields": "true"
        }
    }
]
```

}